# How to provide macOS (iMac-Catalina) with equivalent to MS RDP Server?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, desktop, remote-control

How to provide macOS (iMac-Catalina) with equivalent to MS RDP Server?

I'm losing the Win-10 laptop RDS server and want to migrate that functionality to the iMac.

BTW, I've been using the MS RDS client on several platforms and it's fine for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS it’s included in the [sharing system preference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop).

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-the-screen-of-another-mac-mh14066/mac

You can find a lot of details here under the [remote-desktop](/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) in addition to the Apple support pages and help. I do not think anyone has implemented a perfect match for the RDS protocol, so you’ll need to adjust with different clients, but remote screen, keyboard, mouse and file transfer functions should all be familiar to you.